# Django 1.3 static files and displaying content

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new to django, I'm trying to load a js file and image, the system of views and templates. But I have problems. Developing my configuration is as follows.

IN SETTINGS.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'E:/GIS/recursos/js',
)

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

)
```

URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^prueba/', current_datetime),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The page loads but not the static files in the logs I see

```
[14/Apr/2011 10:55:41] "GET /prueba/ HTTP/1.1" 200 631
[14/Apr/2011 10:55:41] "GET /prueba/prueba.js HTTP/1.1" 200 631
[14/Apr/2011 10:55:41] "GET /prueba/img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 631
[14/Apr/2011 10:55:41] "GET /prueba/img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 631
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

your static files should be served at `/static/` not `/prueba/` as your logs indicate... check your template.

**edit:**

some things to check:

1. check your settings.py file and see that

   ```
       'django.core.context_processors.static',
   ```

   is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`
2. check to see if `DEBUG=True`
3. check that you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in your installed apps.
4. Read the django [**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for managing static files and [**`context processors`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor)

   > As a brief refresher, context
   >   processors add variables into the
   >   contexts of every template. However,
   >   context processors require that you
   >   use RequestContext when rendering
   >   templates. This happens automatically
   >   if you're using a generic view, but in
   >   views written by hand you'll need to
   >   explicitally use RequestContext To see
   >   how that works, and to read more
   >   details, check out Subclassing
   >   Context: RequestContext.

Comment: this is my templete:   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello!</title>
  
     <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}prueba.js"></script>

    <script>
        prueba();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>

It is now{{current_date}}.

<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img.jpg" />

</body>
</html>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello!</title>
  
     <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}prueba.js"></script>

    <script>
        prueba();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>

It is now{{current_date}}.

<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img.jpg" />

</body>
</html>

Comment: I added the first point, already had DBEG = True but it still does not work, keep looking at the path '/ prueba/ '.

any idea?

thanks in advance
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time with this new static file app, but I got it working now. Your `settings.py` seems pretty ok to me. Apparently the trick is to use the proper `context_instance` at your view. There is no need to use `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` in development mode.

So this is what I added in my view:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

[...]
def my_view(request):
   [...] 
   return render_to_response("templatename.html", {'form': form},
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or you could also use the `render` shortcut, which works like the `render_to_response` with a `RequestContext`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

[...]
def my_view(request):
   [...] 
   return render(request, 'templatename.html', {'form': form})
```

HTH

reference: http://groups.google.com/group/pyweb-il/browse_thread/thread/957d6215e3716fa7?pli=1